# Remove space above `itemize` list within table environment

Tags: tables, lists, enumitem

I want to include an `itemize`-list inside a `table`-environment, in a compact way to save space. However, there is a large gap above the list when in the table, but not when after a paragraph in normal text:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
%\usepackage[autooneside=false, headsepline, plainheadsepline, automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\linespread{1}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{enumitem} % enumerate?
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
some text
\begin{compactitem}  \item  point1  \item point2 \end{compactitem}
\begin{table}[ht!]
    \setlength{\leftmargini}{7pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l | X | X }\hline \hline
        & ECB& FED\\ \hline
    M1 & \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=0pt]   \item  point1  \item point2 \end{itemize} 
      & \begin{compactitem}  \item  point1  \item point2   \end{compactitem}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, I tested both the `compactitem` from `paralist` package, as well as `itemize` from `enumitem` with its options `[noitemsep,topsep=0pt]`. They produce slightly different heights. This works between normal paragraphs, but in the table, it does not. **I would want the "point1" to be at the same level as the "M1".**

[image]

---

This one, with a slight indent that is visible when there is a line break (the word "Assets" starts a bit further to the right than the word "during"), is the result of

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}\begin{compactitem}
 \item Assets can be \textbf{difficult to value} during periods of hyperinflation
\end{compactitem}\end{minipage}
```

[image]

---

**Comparing the two proposed solutions:** The following MWE compares the two solutions directly, defining new environments, respectively, named `compactitemt` and `compactitemm`.

```
\documentclass%[12pt,abstracton,titlepage,parskip=false, no, no,twoside=true,open=right]
{scrbook}
%\usepackage[autooneside=false, headsepline, plainheadsepline, automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

%\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{paralist}
%\usepackage{newtxtext}%antpolt mathpazo %\usepackage{mathptmx} %\usepackage{newtxtext} 
\usepackage{enumitem} % enumerate?
\newenvironment{compactitemm}{\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}\begin{compactitem}}{\end{compactitem}\end{minipage}} %this solution requires enumitem package
\newenvironment{compactitemt}{\begin{itemize}[nosep, wide=0pt,
  %left=0pt %for neat, wide=0pt %for flush left to save space
  before={\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}},
  after ={\end{minipage}} ]   }{ \end{itemize} }
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength{\leftmargini}{7pt} %this impacts the left margin of itemize package, i.e. ``stuff 2'' in table. 7pt aligns with the other solution. 
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X | X }\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{stuff 1}\\ \hline
\begin{compactitemt}
  \item x This line should break and we see where the next begins
  \item y
  \item z
\end{compactitemt}
& \begin{compactitemt}
  \item a This line should break and we see where the next begins
  \item b
\end{compactitemt}\\ \hline 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{stuff 2}\\ \hline
\begin{compactitemm}
  \item x This line should break and we see where the next begins
  \item y
  \item z This line should break and we see where the next begins
\end{compactitemm}
& \begin{compactitemm}
  \item a This line should break and we see where the next begins
  \item b
\end{compactitemm}\\ \hline 
\end{tabularx}
\caption{MWE}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- If you use the `compactitem` environment, you need to encase it in `\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}` and `\end{minipage}` statements.
- If you use an `itemize` environment along with the `enumitem` package, you can add the statements

  ```
  before={\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}},
  after ={\end{minipage}}
  ```

  to the list of options that go with `\begin{itemize}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{paralist,enumitem,tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % optional, for a slighly more open "look"
    \setlength{\leftmargini}{7pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l | X | X }
    \hline \hline
       & ECB & FED\\ 
    \hline
    M1 & \begin{itemize}[nosep, left=0pt,
                         before={\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}},
                         after ={\end{minipage}} ]   
         \item point1  
         \item point2 
         \end{itemize} 
       & \begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}
         \begin{compactitem}  
         \item point1  
         \item point2   
         \end{compactitem}
         \end{minipage}\\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. The `minipage`-solution is ideal, because I can define a new environment at the top of the document and thus easily create itemized lists in all tables!
One minor point: when I have a linebreak in an `\item`, it can be seen that the first line is indented. Can this be fixed? I put a photo in the original question.

Comment: @Marie.P. - I'm afraid I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "the first line is indented". To suppress hanging indentation in the `itemize` environment, just replace `left=0pt` with `wide=0pt`.

Comment: I edited the question for more clarity. Would you perhaps also have an idea how that works for the `compactitem`-environment?

Answer (score 4):

For the space above, it is enough to make LaTeX believe the cell is a minipage. For this, I borrowed a `\compress` command found in an answer to a question on this site. For the space below, you have to add a negative \baselineskip at the end.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
%\usepackage[autooneside=false, headsepline, plainheadsepline, automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\linespread{1}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{enumitem} % enumerate?
\usepackage{tabularx}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
some text
\begin{compactitem} \item point1 \item point2 \end{compactitem}
\begin{table}[ht!]
    \setlength{\leftmargini}{7pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l | >{\compress}X |>{\compress} X }\hline \hline
        & ECB& FED\\ \hline
    M1 & \begin{itemize}[nosep, after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}] \item point1 \item point2 \end{itemize}\\
\hline
    & & \begin{compactitem} \item point1 \item point2 \end{compactitem}\leavevmode\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
       \\
\hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: For that, I borroweda `` \copress` command found a]